# Magento: How to change PHP from 5.3 to 5.4?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Magento version: 1.7.0.2
I am currently running PHP 5.3.29, given recent security patch update its recommended to have PHP 5.4 and up.

My question: How to safety upgrade PHP version? Is there a chance of website crash and extension incompatibility?

Comment: Absolutely there is a chance of it crashing. You should upgrade PHP, enable developer mode and regression test everything before you deploy the changes to production.

Answer (score 1):

> My question: How to safety upgrade PHP version? Is there a chance of website crash and extension incompatibility?

Yes, there's a chance that your system contains code that works in PHP 5.3, but won't work in PHP 5.4.

You safely upgrade by

1. Creating a test server and installing PHP 5.4
2. Transferring your code to that test system, via a source control repository
3. Test you checkout flow and important business workflows
4. Fix any bugs
5. Once you have a working code base, setup another test server and develop an automated deployment process
6. Fix bugs in your deployment process
7. Once you have a smooth deployment process, upgrade PHP 5.4 on your actual server, and deploy your Magento system to that server.

Comment: If the module developers did their job properly and the site owner has upgraded all third party modules to the latest versions as required by the **SUPEE-6788** patch, made sure the **PHP 5.4 patch for 1.6.x.x and up** that is available in the Release Archive is installed, followed by Alan's test steps above on any user generated modules/templates, things should work just fine on PHP 5.4